# How do I go about removing values found in one cell out of another cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, duplicates

I have an Excel sheet where I have two columns with certain "keys" in every cell, like column A cell 1 would look like

`|55|56|60|99|120|` and column B cell 1 would look basically the same but just with different values, like `|55|56|62|100|121|130|210|312|`.

Now what I need is to remove every occurrence in column A cell 1 that also occurs in column B cell 1 and so on. In the end I want to have a third cell that only shows "`|60|99|120|`".

I cannot find anything online that tells me how to "compare" two cells with each other and remove duplicates. All I can find is the filter option that would compare cells in column A and remove the ones that have appeared exactly like that before, but that is not what I need. What I did find was a VBA module that almost did what I wanted, but it only removed one instance of the duplicate and kept the original.

I need to do this for about 450 columns, so doing this manually would be a chore and it would help with future tasks.

Answer (score 4):

Try using the following formula:

[image]

---

```
=LET(x, TEXTSPLIT(A1,"|",,1), "|"&TEXTJOIN("||",,FILTER(x,ISERR(SEARCH(x,B1))))&"|")
```

---

As OP's comment in another answer, they have single pipes `|` hence editing the answer, there is not much difference it my previous answer and the updated one:

[image]

---

```
=LET(x, TEXTSPLIT(A1,"|",,1), "|"&TEXTJOIN("|",,FILTER(x,ISERR(SEARCH(x,B1))))&"|")
```

---

- Using `LET()` function to define variables therefore eliminating or reducing the use of redundant formulas/ranges.
- The variable `x` is defined for splitting the cell value in `A1` which uses `TEXTSPLIT()` function to split by delimiter `|` by column wise, and excludes if any empties.
- Using the above variable in `SEARCH()` function to find the position of the `x` in cell value `B1`
- The above returns a number else error, hence used `ISERR()` which returns `TRUE` reversing it with `1-` to make it `FALSE` for that returned error and `TRUE` for the number, alternatively this `1-ISERR()` can be replaced with `ISNUMBER()`
- Using `FILTER()` function grabbing the one have returned `TRUE` and lastly joining the array within `TEXTJOIN()` with a delimiter `|` to return the required output.

---

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for the fast reply.

Comment: Hey, sorry to just write this now. When i Copy & paste the formula into C1 i get the Error "The first Argument of LET must be a valid name". Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Yes it could be possible, change the `x` as `_x` like this or `_split`. So the formula becomes as `=LET(_split, TEXTSPLIT(A1,"|",,1), "|"&TEXTJOIN("||",,FILTER(_split,ISERR(SEARCH(_split,B1))))&"|")`

Comment: I still get the same error when i use either =LET(_x, TEXTSPLIT(A1,"|",,1), "|"&TEXTJOIN("||",,FILTER(_x,ISERR(SEARCH(_x,B1))))&"|") or =LET(_split, TEXTSPLIT(A1,"|",,1), "|"&TEXTJOIN("||",,FILTER(_split,ISERR(SEARCH(_split,B1))))&"|")

Comment: What error are you getting? error type, can you show me a screenshot ? also do you use comma as a separator or semicolon?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/oDTleiP

Comment: I usually use Semicolons as seperators

Comment: @Leon can you change all the commas into semicolons. `=LET(_split; TEXTSPLIT(A1;"|";;1), "|"&TEXTJOIN("||";;FILTER(_split;ISERR(SEARCH(_split;B1))))&"|")`

Comment: @Leon yes then use the way I have commented above, its because of regional settings or the type of separators you have set in your PC

Comment: You missed one comma after |;;1) but after chaning it to a semicolon using =LET(_split; TEXTSPLIT(A1;"|";;1); "|"&TEXTJOIN("||";;FILTER(_split;ISERR(SEARCH(_split;B1))))&"|") finally worked. Thank you very much, you are a lifesaver my man

Comment: A well-explained solution before the powerful instrument of the lambda formula +:)

Answer (score 4):

**Try**:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=REDUCE(A1,TEXTSPLIT(B1,"|",,1),LAMBDA(x,y,SUBSTITUTE(x,"|"&y&"|","|")))
```

---

**Explanation**:

You can look at `LAMBDA()` as an iterative process. The function is available as a stand-alone function for users, but MS made several lambda-helpers available that utilize this iterative concept. One of such functions is `REDUCE()`.

This function specifically could be seen as an iterative process where a starting input is altered and saved upon each iteration. In this specific case our 1st parameter is the content of cell `A1`. Our 2nd parameter holds an array, obtained through splitting the content of cell `B1` by the delimiter '|'. The 3rd parameter holds the actual iterative lambda process where we first named our variables (our first two parameters).

Thus within each iteration the variable 'x' holds the output of the last iteration, and variable 'y' holds the next element in line from our array of numbers. Another way of looking at it would be to think of an accumulator and a current value if you are more familiar with those concepts.

To visualize this a little bit:

| i | X | Y | New_X |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | |55|56|60|99|120| | 55 | |56|60|99|120| |
| 2 | |56|60|99|120| | 56 | |60|99|120| |
| 3 | |60|99|120| | 100 | |60|99|120| |
| 4 | |60|99|120| | 121 | |60|99|120| |
| 5 | |60|99|120| | 130 | |60|99|120| |
| 6 | |60|99|120| | 210 | |60|99|120| |
| 7 | |60|99|120| | 312 | |60|99|120| |

Here 'New_X' is generated through `SUBSTITUTE(X,"|"&Y&"|","|")` and is going to be the input in the next iteration.

---

**Note**: OP mentioned he shared the wrong dummy data where all double pipe-symbols should be swapped out for single ones.

Comment: This one worked better for longer strings but i typed up a little mistake above. My form actually looks like this  "|55|56|60|99|120|" and not this  "|55||56||60||99||120|". It messes up the format the formula gives me. What would i need to remove/add to the formula so it it would work for the format "|55|56|60|99|120|"? Thank you very much for your previous Answer!

Comment: Simply use `=REDUCE(A1,TEXTSPLIT(B1,"|",,1),LAMBDA(x,y,SUBSTITUTE(x,"|"&y&"|","|")))` where the only difference would be that we replace the text with a pipe-symbol instead of empty string. @Leon

Comment: Thanks alot, that worked perfectly. I´m still a total beginner in Excel, could you maybe explain what each part of the formula does? Especially the LAMBDA part confuses me!

Comment: @Leon, added some background as to the *how*.

Comment: Yeah i really should have edited the post, afterwards. I only noticed this when testing with @JvdV formula else i would have mentioned it in the other comments

Comment: @Leon nevermind i have edited your post to make it generic

Comment: One of the most instructive explanations of the newer dynamic Excel functions I know, especially regarding lambda as iterative process +:)